# Add minutes to time with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table of trading hours like this:

```
CREATE TABLE trading_hours(
        id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        time_open TIME NOT NULL,
        duration INTEGER NOT NULL, -- In minutes
        day_of_week INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week) VALUES (1, '6:00', 720, 1); -- sun 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week) VALUES (2, '6:10', 720, 2); -- mon 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week) VALUES (3, '6:20', 720, 3); -- tue 12 hours
INSERT INTO trading_hours(id, time_open, duration, day_of_week) VALUES (4, '16:30', 780, 4); -- wed 13 hours
```

I with to create the closing time, but adding the duration, to the time_open field.
I have tried using `SEC_TO_TIME()` and `TIMESTAMPADD()`, however, if the resulting time is greater than 23:59:59, the results return times like 27:00:00.

Rather than the time being 27:00:00 I would like to see it as 03:00:00 to reflect the time the shop closes.

What I have tried:

```
SELECT th.time_open, duration, 
       ADDTIME(th.time_open, SEC_TO_TIME(th.duration*60)) AS time_close 
FROM   trading_hours th;
```

```
SELECT th.time_open, th.duration, 
       TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,th.duration, th.time_open) AS close_time 
FROM   trading_hours th;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TIME_TO_SEC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) and [`SEC_TO_TIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) to get your desired result; the key is to do the addition modulo 86,400 (the number of seconds in a day):

```
SELECT *, 
       SEC_TO_TIME((TIME_TO_SEC(time_open) + duration * 60) % 86400) AS time_closed
FROM trading_hours
```

Output

```
id  time_open   duration    day_of_week     time_closed
1   06:00:00    720         1               18:00:00
2   06:10:00    720         2               18:10:00
3   06:20:00    720         3               18:20:00
4   16:30:00    780         4               05:30:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1867886cc9dbcf14e14b6eccd35fdd09)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `addtime` function as described here:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.7-en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_addtime

Answer (score -1):

Mine is working in MySQL like

```
SELECT *, ( ADDTIME( time_open ,  STR_TO_DATE( CONCAT( "0", FLOOR( duration / 60 ), ":", MOD ( duration , 60 ),":00" ),"%H:%i:%s" ))) AS time_closed FROM 
trading_hours
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).